# Flashing UITableView scrollIndicators in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

In iOS6 I use to have a trick to get the scroll indicators to flash in a `UITableView`:

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    if (self.superview)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(flashScrollIndicators) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    }
}
```

However in iOS7 this seems to not work anymore (it worked in iOS 6), and neither does just doing: `[self flashScrollIndicators]`.

Has anyone figured out a way to get the scroll indicators to flash in iOS7?

Comment: You're sure that `didMoveToSuperview` is being called, right?

Comment: @undo - Yes it is, just checked.

Comment: Dumb question: You have enough content in your tableview for the scroll indicators to appear?

Comment: @undo - Yeah I do. Should've mentioned that the above code is working fine in iOS6, so I think this might just be a bug in iOS7.

Comment: I experimented with this a bit and they always flashed for me. My guess is that it's a sequence problem, i.e. you're populating the table after it moves to superview. Can you share your view controller code or give some reproduction steps?

Comment: @TimothyMoose - sorry for the late late response, but I think you're correct. Do you want to put this up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's a sequence problem, i.e. you're populating the table after it moves to superview. To fix the issue, either:

1. Populate the table earlier in the process like `viewDidLoad`
2. Explicitly flash the indicators after the table has been populated